# FusionAuth incomplete reindex with AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, fusionauth

I am migrating from a self-hosted Elasticsearch FusionAuth search to an AWS Elasticsearch Service solution.

I have a new FusionAuth app EC2 instance reading from the in-use database that is configured to use the new Elasticsearch service.

On triggering a reindex from the new app instance I see that only around 60k or 62.5k documents are being written to the new index when I am expecting roughly 6mil.

I see no errors from AWS's Elasticsearch Service and in the app's logs I can see: (endpoint intentionally omitted)

```
Feb 13, 2020 10:18:46.116 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.service.search.ElasticSearchClientProvider - Connecting to FusionAuth Search Engine at [https://vpc-<<omitted>>.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com]
13-Feb-2020 11:19:55.176 INFO [http-nio-9011-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:430)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
"/usr/local/fusionauth/logs/fusionauth-app.log" [readonly] 43708L, 4308629C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               42183,1       96%
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.client.domain.documents.IndexUser.<init>(IndexUser.java:79)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.ElasticsearchSearchEngine.lambda$index$1(ElasticsearchSearchEngine.java:140)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.ElasticsearchSearchEngine.index(ElasticsearchSearchEngine.java:140)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.user.ReindexRunner$ReindexWorker.run(ReindexRunner.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.client.domain.documents.IndexUser.<init>(IndexUser.java:79)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.ElasticsearchSearchEngine.lambda$index$1(ElasticsearchSearchEngine.java:140)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.ElasticsearchSearchEngine.index(ElasticsearchSearchEngine.java:140)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.user.ReindexRunner$ReindexWorker.run(ReindexRunner.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.NullPointerException
Feb 18, 2020 10:23:29.064 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.service.user.ReindexRunner - Reindex completed in [86797] ms or [86] seconds.
```

Although there are some exceptions there is also an "Reindex completed" INFO log at the end.

Not knowing the ins-and-outs of Elasticsearch I'm also not sure where to start in investigating a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the re-index operation is taking an exception which is likely the cause of the truncated index.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.search.client.domain.documents.IndexUser.<init>(IndexUser.java:79)
```

This code makes an assumption that you have a username or email address. This should be enforced by the FusionAuth APIs. But in this case, for this exception to occur the email and username are both `NULL`.

How did you get users into the db, using the Import API, User API, or something else?

In theory you should find at least one user with a `NULL` value for the email and username.

This query - or similar - should find the offending user, then we need to identify how this user was added to FusionAuth.

```
SELECT email, username from identities WHERE email IS NULL OR username IS NULL
```

Comment: We used the Import API to import the bulk of our users into the DB.

And as we have already indexed all of our users into another index I wouldn't have expected the database to have bad data.

I checked it anyway and there are no instances of a user that has neither an email or username, or any without just an email.

Comment: is there a way to change the indexing batch size? it seems to me that it's currently 2.5k batch synced each time, and it fails after 25 runs. I'd like to try modifying it to try and find some sort of pattern. None of our data is NULL

Comment: I've noticed that the log mentiones: /mappings/user.json - is there anywhere we can find it? The username is null for us, but the emails is not null for anyone

Comment: @KasiaGogolek The defaults can be modified, add these two values to `fusionauth.properties`, `fusionauth-app.reindex-batch-size` and `fusionauth-app.reindex-thread-count`. (requires restart) We recently reduced the default to 1k batch size with 2 threads. If you're on an older version it was 5 threads w/ 2.5k batch size. This was a bit aggressive for smaller systems.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek re: `user.json` that is our base mapping for the user, you can always query Elastic for the current mapping values via an Elastic API.

Comment: @JackBooth If you cannot find a user in the database missing an email and username then I am at a loss. If you have support you can open a ticket with FusionAuth for further assistance.